# How to obtain precise spacing between lines for a document and for a specific section?

Tags: line-spacing

I want to add a special spacing for my document, but all the solution i found like `\onehalfspacing` are not configurable as i want.

And some exemple showed on this website doesn't work for me ...

Do you have any idea to precise spacing between lines for a document and for a specific section ?

My document is an article

Comment: In order to "precise spacing between lines" use TeX registers `\baselineskip`, `\lineskip`, (`\lineskiplimit`) and `\parskip`. You can set any "skip" values to these registers.

Answer (score 0):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
\fontsize{10}{5}\selectfont
\lipsum[1-3]

\fontsize{10}{30}\selectfont
\lipsum[4-6]    
\end{document}
```

Comment: Do you know the default value of the fontsize ? I'm using Lettrine package, does this exemple could be fine with the fontsize of the lettrine ?